# Vaadin-addons Maven POM File Configuration

Tags: maven, vaadin

I can't get a Vaadin + Spring project built due to vaadin-addons while someone can get it built. The pom file already has the addons repository. The following is the structure of the pom.xml. What is missing? Is the addons repository in a wrong place?

```
  <dependencies>
        …
        <!-- Vaadin dependencies -->
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
              <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
              <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
              <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
              <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
              <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
              <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
              <artifactId>vaadin-combobox-multiselect</artifactId>
              <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
              <artifactId>vaadin-grid-util</artifactId>
              <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
  …
  </dependencies>
 ...
  <profiles>
     <profile>
             <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
              <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
              <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
              </activation>
              <repositories>
          ...
                    <repository>
                          <id>vaadin-addons</id>
                          <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
                    </repository>
              </repositories>
```

**Update:**
I solve this probule by adding the following in the pom file

```
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
  <snapshots>
     <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
 </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>vaadin-addons</id>
  <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
  <snapshots>
     <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
 </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>sonatype vaadin</id>
  <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin/</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
  <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
 <pluginRepository>
  <id>central</id>
  <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
 </pluginRepository>
 <pluginRepository>
  <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
  <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
 </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Can you share your entire POM please? A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful!

Comment: This site doesn't allow me to post the whole pom file for the reason of "too much code". I try to put as much information as I can in the post. I had to try multiple times to get it posted.  All related data is in the post.

Comment: On one hand, this site sets up a standard of posts. On the other hand, this site sets up restrictions to prevent people post a qualified post.

Comment: First you should use a repository manager in your environment furthermore you have to use `https`. instead of `http` and of course the key to access vaadin add-on repository...

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a profile with the id `<id>vaadin-prerelease</id>` and the repositories are defined only under that profile. I think this is not what you want; instead, you should define the `<repositories>` on the same level as `<dependencies>`. Repositories for a specific profile are only used if you're building with that profile enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have resolved the problem. As you said, I add the vaadin-prerelease. Vaddin-addons is rare for some reason.